# Rails serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it safe to use such serializers as Active Model Serializer and fast_jsonapi, which are not supported anymore?
And what serializers are the fastest and the best to use in a small project and at all?

Comment: In general, it is not a good idea to add a gem to a project when that gem is unmaintained. It still might work in its current state but it might not work anymore with the next Ruby or Ruby on Rails version and you would have to replace it then. It certainly makes more sense to bet on well-maintained gems that still get updates and have a huge user base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project isn't really big, then IMO don't add additional dependencies & keep it simple by:

```rb
# Use ActiveRecord build-ins:
user = User.find(id)

# one of these:
user_hash = user.attributes
user_hash = user.as_json
user_hash = user.serializable_hash
user_hash = user.serializable_hash(
  except: [:first_name, :last_name],
  methods: :full_name,
  include: { posts: { only: 'title' } },
)

render json: user_hash
```

or

```rb
# Write your own simple renderers for a particular purpose/feature
module ProfileFeature
  module Renderers
    @renderers = {
      User => lambda do |user|
        { name: user.name, pic_url: user.profile_pic_url }
      end
    }

    def self.[](klass)
      @renderers.fetch(klass)
    end
  end

  def self.render(obj)
    Renderers[obj.class].call(obj)
  end
end


render json: ProfileFeature.render(user)
```